# Can I have a K8s pod per user/firm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there a way we can have a K8s pod per user/per firm? I realise, per user/per firm  grouping is mixing up the business level semantics with infrastructure but say I had this need for regulatory reasons, etc to keep things separate. Then is there a way to create a pod on the fly when a user logs in for the first time and hold this pod reference and route any further requests to the relevant pod which will host a set of containers each running an instance of one of the modules.

1. Is this even possible?
2. If possible, what are those identifiers that
   can be injected into the pod on the fly that I could use to identify that this is
   USER-A-POD vs USER_B_POD or FIRM_A_POD vs FIRM_B_POD ?
   Effectively, I need to have a pod template that helps me create identical pods of 1 replica but the only way they differ is they are serving traffic related to one user/one firm only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you want to send traffic to a specific pod say from a [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) you would use [Labels and Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/). For example, using the selector `app: usera-app` in the Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: usera-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: usera-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Then say if the [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for your pods, using the label `app: usera-app`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: usera-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: usera-app
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: usera-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myservice
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)

How you assign your pods and deployments is up to you and whatever configuration you may use.  If you'd like to force create some of the labels in deployments/pods you can take a look at [MutatingAdminssionWebhooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook).

If you are looking at projects to facilitate all this you can take a look at:

- [Gatekeeper](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper) which is an implementation of the [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/) for Kubernetes admission. (Still in alpha as of this writing)

Other tools that can help you with attestation and admission mechanism (would have to be adapted for labels):

- [Kritis](https://github.com/grafeas/kritis)
- [Portieris](https://github.com/IBM/portieris)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create multiple virtual clusters for each user with namespaces.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/

Namespaces are the way to divide cluster between users.